# django how to define models for existing many to many tables in postgresql database

Tags: django, postgresql, many-to-many

I have an existing PostgreSQL database with a many to many relationship, it is handled through a join table as below.

I'm looking to apply the ManyToMany Field type, does this bypass this join/intermediate table? How do I correctly configure it in my models.py? I'd rather keep the intermediate table.

```
# models.py
class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
...

class JoinSampleContainer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    container_id = models.ForeignKey(Container, db_column='container_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample, db_column='sample_id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
...

class Container(models.Model):
    container_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `ManyToManyField` on one of your models (e.g. `Sample`) specifying a `through` option as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    id = ...
    containers = models.ManyToManyField(Container, through='JoinSampleContainer', through_fields=('sample_id', 'container_id'),
        related_name='samples')
```

Note: You should name the fields in your models for readability (and use `db_column` to specify the DB column that is used). Use `id` instead of `sample_id`, it's much more readable to use `sample.id` instead of `sample.sample_id`. And use `sample` instead of `sample_id`, resp `container` instead of `container_id` on the through model.