# Setting up a foreign key relationship in Django using postgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, entity-relationship

I want to model the following entity relationship in Django using PostgreSQL:

```
  ---------                 ------------------                 --------------- 
 |objective|----1:Many---- |userToObjective| ----Many:1----|acounts_account|
  ---------                 ------------------                 ---------------
```

Objective and Accounts are 2 different Django applications and I am using this code to have create my table data structure:

```
# models.py Objective
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Import the user model from the Accounts application
User = get_user_model()

class Objective(models.Model):
    id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    objective       = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=60)
    initial_date    = models.DateField(default=timezone.now(), null=False)
    expiration_date = models.DateField()
    users           = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserToObjective', through_fields=('user','objective'), related_name='objectives')


class UserToObjective(models.Model):
    id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user      = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    objective = models.ForeignKey(Objective, db_column='id', on_delete = models.PROTECT)


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# models.py Accounts

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    id           = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email        = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    last_login   = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I applied the migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations` I encounter the following error:

```
objective.Objective.users: (fields.E339) 'UserToObjective.objective' is not a foreign key to 'Account'.
HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Account': user?
objective.Objective.users: (fields.E339) 'UserToObjective.user' is not a foreign key to 'Objective'.
HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Objective': objective?
objective.UserToObjective: (models.E007) Field 'objective' has column name 'id' that is used by another field.
HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
objective.UserToObjective: (models.E007) Field 'user' has column name 'id' that is used by another field.
HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
```

What setup am I missing? Any advice or help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your question talks about a relationship between Account and Objective (with a model ObjectiveToAccount) but your models only have a relationship between User and Objective. Can you make sure your problem statement corresponds to the code you're showing????

Comment: The User model was customized, so Account is the class model but I need to import it as User.

Comment: First why define a through model if you're not adding any information on it anyway? Just do a m2m without through, it would be much easier. Second, reverse the `through_fields`, the first one should be `objective` the second one `user`, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields). Finally [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to understand why you get the `db_column` error.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to implement this 1:many then many:1 relationship is because I thought this will give me some problems later when doing querysets, such as degradation in time retrieval.

Comment: But m2m does exactly the same (except it's transparent to you). ie. django creates the intermediate table anyway. The advantage is that you can just create the relationship much more easily: `objective.users.add(my_user)` will just work whereas with the `through` relationship it won't work. You'll have to create the actual `UsersToObjective` object.

Comment: I thought that wasn’t the case because I am using PostgreSQL instead of the default SQLite, thus, that’s why I ended up in this diagram.

Comment: Where did you read that? ManyToManyField works fine on postgresql.

Comment: Looking at some old questions such as this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/54763524/2514936 and this tutorial https://youtu.be/2KqhBkMv7aM I will be implementing your changes now.

Comment: The first post is about **existing tables** in the database. Not starting from scratch. I don't know about the youtube video, not gonna watch it :-)

Comment: I see, I thought in that question the user started from scratch so I decided to follow his approach. I will clarify this in the question and my answer. Indeed, don't watch the video ;-)

Comment: The `through` table would make sense if for example you intend to store an `achieved_date` for when each user achieves the objective. Or a progress field. Look at the docs I mentioned above (with the `Membership` example), it makes it clear.